# CodeIgniter: How to use and operator in WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i use the simple query in my sql like

```
$query="update employee set employee_salary=employee_salary+ '".$bones.'" where employee_id='".$data['employee_id']."' and employee_code='".$data['employee_code']."'";
```

i use the following code but does not work as below

```
$this->db->where('employee_id', $data['employee_id']);
$this->db->where('employee_code', $data['employee_code']);
$this->db->set('employee_salary', 'employee_salary+ $bones', FALSE);
$this->db->update('spar_m_in_out');
```

Now i want to update employee salary update with current value with bones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable isn't interpreted since it's inside single quotes, and gets passed down as is.

Concatenate the string so as to evaluate the variable and pass it as a whole string expression to the DB:

```
$this->db->set('employee_salary', 'employee_salary + '.$bones, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should update the third line as below:

```
$employee_salary  =   $employee_salary + $bones
$this->db->set('employee_salary', $employee_salary ), FALSE);
```

Comment: yes it will work.. Try to debug using `echo $this->db->last_query();`